# Working of '\b' with '\n' in C

Tags: c, formatting, printf

In one of my programs I needed to delete previously written characters from console.
The thing which was previously on the console was written by the code below:

```
printf("Hello World!\n");
```

Now I did:

```
printf("\b\b\bhwg");
```

The output was:

```
Hello World!
hwg
```

While the expected output is:

```
Hello Worlhwg
```

Not using `\n` after `"Hello World"` works though!

Comment: `\b` is "backspace", which moves the cursor back one space, deletes the character under the cursor and repositions the remained of the line.  Since you used a `\n` newline, the cursor was moved to the beginning of a new line.  The cursor cannot move back when it's at the beginning of a line.

Comment: You cannot delete over lines with `\b`. You would need special escape sequences depending on the terminal. Often just `\r' is used to revert the cursor, but this works also only on the same line.

Comment: This is not related to C but to the terminal you are using. If you were using teletype  as your IO device, you wouldn't expect backspaces to work, right?

Comment: `printf` does not understand "console" it simply sends to the standard output stream.

Comment: There is no "situation" described to provide a WA to.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  All I ask is a procedure to get the desired output.

Comment: Re edit: the workaround seems to suggest itself: don't output a newline until you are sure you want to move to the new line. If the output doesn't appear (is still buffered) you can `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: The only general workaround I could think of was wrapping all `printf()` in your own function which buffers the output and interpretes `\b` itself. You wouldn't have any output though until a call of `myconsolefflush()` or whatever ..

Comment: Please provide a concrete answer.

Comment: You deleted the comment which said you "have to type a newline" and you are unlikely to get a concrete answer. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem: the actual problem involving arrays which you mentioned, not a different fictitious problem.